# mysql insert...select statement causing deadlock in concurrent request

Tags: mysql, select, insert, database-deadlocks

MySQL version 5.7
Engine : InnoDB

I have table called "md_waiting_slot_count" and it has following columns:

```
cell | popupDate | userId | creationTime
```

Now I have following query:

```
insert into md_waiting_slot_count 
select cell, '2017-08-31' as pd, 'abnc' as ui, '2017-08-26 15:55:51'  
from 
(select sum(slotcount) as tt, cell from 
( select 0 as slotcount, cell_str as cell, 'master' from cell where 
cell_str in 
("Gujarat_Jamnagar_Jamnagar_00-18_Male","Gujarat_Jamnagar_Jamnagar_19-
22_Male")  

union all  

select slotcount, cell, wting from
(select count(*) as slotcount, cell as cell, 'waiting' as wting from 
md_waiting_slot_count where 
cell in(SELECT cell_str as cell FROM cell where cell_str 
in("Gujarat_Jamnagar_Jamnagar_00-18_Male","Gujarat_Jamnagar_Jamnagar_19-
22_Male")) 
and popupDate='2017-08-31' and creationTime > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 
20 MINUTE) group by cell ) as t1

union all  

select filledslotcount as slotcount, id as cell, 'final' from 
md_slot_count where id in(
SELECT cell_str as cell FROM cell where cell_str 
in("Gujarat_Jamnagar_Jamnagar_00-18_Male","Gujarat_Jamnagar_Jamnagar_19-
22_Male")) 
and popupSlotDate='2017-08-31' ) t group by cell having tt < 4) as ft 
order by cell, pd, ui
on duplicate key update creationTime = "'2017-08-26 15:55:51'";
```

Here 2 other table also used which are as follow

`md_slot_count
id| popupDate| state| district| taluka| ageGroup| gender| filledSlotCount`

`cell
cell_str| state| district| taluka| ageGroup| gender`

This insert...select statement causing deadlock after 3-4 successful run.

Help me with this.
How to see "last deadlock log" in MySQL?

I want to do something like this

> Transaction 1 --> evaluate above query --> insert row
>
> Transaction 2  --> evaluate above query --> insert row

Here when second transaction evaluate query it has to consider the data inserted by previous transaction. Here I want to allow max 4 transaction to insert row, no more than that. So the evaluated query allow to insert then only insert.

Now in parallel request if those 2 process of query evaluation and insertion is separate and no consider previous transaction data, then more then 4 transaction can come and insert data.

So the ultimate goal is to

> If one transaction begin and read data and fulfil the condition then insert data and mean while no one else make insertion, and as the first transaction complete, the second transaction has to consider all the updated data only. So either complete or nothing for one transaction and other transaction has to wait. **I do not achieve in concurrent request, as all read together and so it read old data so all are able to add data in table. 
>   So I take this whole in one single query.**

Comment: You are inserting into `md_waiting_slot_count` and at the same time also selecting from this table during the insert.  On top of this, sometimes you do an update to this table.  My guess is that this structure is the source of the deadlock.  Is there any way you can avoid doing the insert this way?

Comment: You are union all diffrent  number and type of column  1: select cell, '2017-08-31' as pd, 'abnc' as ui, '2017-08-26 15:55:51'    2: select slotcount, cell, wting.. sure this query work??????

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen  I do this because, I want to do insert only if the select query evaluate success and return rows, otherwise not. if these are 2 separate query then in concurrent request it insert more then 4 rows which I mention in having clause in above query. This separate statement not work in concurrent request.

Comment: @scaisEdge  yes, this query works correctly.

Comment: @DhavalBhoot Well try to rephrase the query so you don't need to select from the same table during insertion.  This is the first thing I would try.

Comment: You have  four column in the first  select  , 3 in the second select,  2 in the third select  .. and this select work ? .. could be i don't read the column but seems you have different number of columns in union and this in mysql is not allowed ..

Comment: @scaisEdge this works, as all 3 inner query has the same 3 column and has group by on column "cell" It works correctly, otherwise how can I say the deadlock occurs. And after all 3 inner query get executed I have given an alias  to to and final query get data from it.

Answer (score 0):

You want to insert into md_waiting_slot_count  some data calculated from md_waiting_slot_count.
So deadlock is unavoidable. Try to create a temporary table containing your values and then insert your values from your temporary table.

Comment: I can not insert data in another temporary table as I want to use in the bellow select query for other next transaction.